# Latex math: indexes not allowed in small matrix

Tags: math-mode

I am using the small matrix in order to represent a matrix in a text, I defined myself a command like:

```
\newcommand{\maText}[2]{\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)}
```

And it works fine if you do something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\newcommand{\maText}[2]{\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)}
\begin{document}
\(
\begin{maText}
a  b
\end{maText}
\)

\end{document}
```

But as soon as I try to input a number with an index like:
     a_{1}

I get the error: Missing { inserted a_

How can I solve my problem :S???

Comment: You have defined a command `\maText` with two arguments so used as `\maText{a}{b}` but you have used it as an environment with no arguments so it is taking the next two arbitrary tokens

Answer (score 4):

You have defined a two argument command, so the usage is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\newcommand{\maText}[2]{\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)}
\begin{document}
\(\maText{a}{b}\)

\(\maText{a_{1}}{b}\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh wow this worked... I think I should start thinking more when I use some stuff :).. But at first it worked without the curled brackets.. But I guess they are there to be sure what is the first and what the second argument?

Comment: @user63716 no it didn't work, it just didn't give an error as it sort of accidentally managed to avoid falling over

Comment: @user63716 (almost) always in tex you can omit `{}` if the argument is a token, you can use `\maTeX a b` if you must you can use `\frac12` instead of `\frac{1}{2}` it just makes it hard to read and error prone when you need to change it to an argument with more than one token

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know this. thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define `maText` as an environment rather than as a command:

```
\newenvironment{maText}[2]%
       {\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2}%
       {\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)}
```

Comment: Hmm but what's #1  and #2 here:-)

Comment: The OP seems to want to use `maText` as an environment,; however, this assumption could be wrong. `#1` would be the element in the first row (`a` in the OP's example), and `#2` would be the element in the second row (`b` in the OP's example). If the elements aren't single tokens, they'll certainly have to be encased in curly braces.

Comment: yes but with a and b as space separated items in the environment body, with the same environment call you'll get the same errors as in the original with #1 and #2 picking up `a` and `_` if the body is `a_{1} b`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - The elements will definitely have to be surrounded by curly braces if they aren't single-character tokens. E.g., one will have to write `{a_{1}}` rather than `a_{1}`. But this is no different for the argument of an environment than it is for the argument of a macro, isn't it?

Comment: yes (I'm not telling you anything you don't know:-) but the environment form here is just weird, put it another way what's the body of the environment (it's just concatenated to the end of the cell started by `#2`...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - As I said, I was guessing the OP wants to use `maText` as an environment rather than as a macro, so that's why I wrote the answer the way I did. I agree with you that it's easier to conceive of `\maText` as a macro.